# Ptr Word8 to ByteString

Tags: haskell, ffi, bytestring

I have an FFI call returning some data bytes (not a `CString`).
Currently, I am using something like the following:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

BS.pack <$> mapM (peekElem ptr) [0 .. n - 1]
```

Is there a more efficient approach to this?  Googling around seems to point towards using `Data.ByteString.Internal`, but that seems to be frowned upon (binding to internal interfaces).  In fact [they don't seem](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) to offer docs for the internal module anymore.  *Is there a more efficient portable approach?*  I constantly run into this problem when dealing with bytes from FFI. I just want:

```
ptrToBs :: Ptr Word8 -> Int -> IO ByteString
ptrToBs buf n = ... -- totally fine if it makes a copy of the buffer
```

(I did check Hoogle first.)

Maybe I am using the wrong type for "raw bytes to be consumed by `Binary.Get` or some other decoding package later"?

Comment: I guess this is exactly what I want. Can you add this as an answer? Bytes are bytes. (I was thinking of strings as being null terminated, but packCStringLen allows me an out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you want to avoid `CString` for the (in my opinion excellent) reason that they are null-terminated. The more principled `CStringLen` does not have this weakness, and so [`packCStringLen :: CStringLen -> IO ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:packCStringLen) should be suitable for your task.